# Does the Don Carlo in the two Verdi operas--Ernani and Don Carlos--pertain to the same historical character?

Tags: history, opera

In the Verdi opera, "Ernani", there is the role of Don Carlo, later Charles V, Holy Roman Emperor, while in the Verdi opera, "Don Carlos", there is the role of Don Carlo, Infante of Spain, son and heir to the King.

Do these two roles pertain to the same historical figure?

Answer (score 2):

[Charles V, Holy Roman Emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_V,_Holy_Roman_Emperor) (from *[Ernani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernani)*) was the paternal grandfather of [Carlos, Prince of Asturias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos,_Prince_of_Asturias) (from *[Don Carlos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Carlos)*).

Comment: Thanks very much--seems to precisely answer the question. Any further convenient reference for this. I guess one could consult a family tree. Thanks, again!

Comment: @PaulB.Slater, the Wikipedia page for Carlos, Price of Asturias contains a family tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos,_Prince_of_Asturias#Ancestors.